# How to prevent onDismiss Callback to be call, in custom AlertDialog with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I was developing an app which I use Jetpack compose to define the UI.

I was implementing some localdatabase such as Room, and I try to implement the remove operation of my items. In order to confirm this operation by the user, I try to design a custom `AlertDialog`, with 2 buttons, one to confirm and another to dismiss  the operation.

My problems comes, due to my dialog execute the call in the confirm button, and dismiss instantly, less than a second, show I try to don't pass the dismis callback, but doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
//At the begining is invisible and show when the user try to remove some pokemon.
@Composable
fun SimpleAlertDialog(
    show: Boolean,
    onConfirm: Unit,
    onDismiss: KFunction0<Unit>
) {
    if(show){
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { onDismiss},
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = {onConfirm})
                { Text(text = "OK") }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = {onDismiss})
                { Text(text = "Cancel") }
            },
            title = { Text(text = "Remove") },
            text = { Text(text = "Would you like to remove the selected pokemon?") },
            properties = DialogProperties(
                dismissOnBackPress = true,
                dismissOnClickOutside = false
            )
        )
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@SuppressLint("LogNotTimber")
@Composable
fun PokedexRoomEntry(
    entry: RoomResponse,
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MyPokemonViewModel
) {
    val defaultDominantColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
    var dominantColor by remember {
        mutableStateOf(defaultDominantColor)
    }
    val showDialogState: Boolean by viewModel.showDialog.collectAsState()
    if(showDialogState){
        SimpleAlertDialog(
            show = showDialogState,
            onConfirm = viewModel.onDialogConfirm(entry.pokemonName),
            onDismiss = viewModel::onDialogDismiss)
    }
    Box(

...
```

Regarding the `showDialogState`, the callback of the dialog in the viewmodel are the following:

```
class MyPokemonViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val localRepository: LocalRepository):
    ViewModel() {

    var pokemonBoughtList = mutableStateOf<List<RoomResponse>>(listOf())
    var loadError = mutableStateOf("")
    var isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)
    // Initial value is false so the dialog is hidden
    private val _showDialog = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val showDialog: StateFlow<Boolean> = _showDialog.asStateFlow()


    fun onOpenDialogClicked() {
        _showDialog.value = true
    }

    fun onDialogConfirm(pokemonToRemove: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _showDialog.value = false
            removePokemon(pokemonToRemove)
        }
    }

    fun onDialogDismiss() {
        _showDialog.value = false
    }
    fun removePokemon(pokemonToRemove: String) = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO){
        isLoading.value = true
        val resp = localRepository.removePokemon(pokemonToRemove = pokemonToRemove)

        when(resp){
            is WrapperResponse.Sucess -> {
                //Nº files removed
                if(resp.data != 0){
                    //Número de filas eliminadas
                    loadError.value = ""
                    isLoading.value = false
                }else{
                    loadError.value = "No se ha podido eliminar el pokemon seleccionado"
                    isLoading.value = false
                }
            }
            is WrapperResponse.Error -> {
                loadError.value = resp.message.toString()
                isLoading.value = false
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said, the diolog is shown when I invoke the onLongPress listener, but almost instanly, the code inside `onConfirm` callback, and then onDismiss callbak are call, without let the user take any action in the dialog.

Comment: You've declared `onConfirm` of type `Unit`. To make it a callback, it should be `() -> Unit`

Comment: Pass with `onConfirm = { viewModel.onDialogConfirm(entry.pokemonName) }` and use it like `onClick = onConfirm`

Comment: The solution was change the declarion to `````() -> Unit`````